# Problem with SQL Query outputting only one result while having two values from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, select

Good day! I'm making a query where I have to select values from two tables with the same values and its working fine but my problem it only displays only one value from my table. For example.

It only displays the `last name` because I'm using `order by desc` but it won't display the next result. What's the problem with my query? Thank you for the help!

But when I removed this line `ORDER BY homeID DESC LIMIT ' . $this_page_first_result . ',' .  $results_per_page . '` The two results were displayed.

```html
Table [Example}

ID    Description
1      FirstName
2      Last name

My query:

$sql='SELECT homepost.homeID, homepost.homeTitle, homepost.homeIntro, homepost.homePost, homeimage.imageName FROM homepost JOIN homeimage ON (homepost.homeID=homeimage.imageID) WHERE homepost.homeID=homeimage.imageID ORDER BY homeID DESC LIMIT ' . $this_page_first_result . ',' .  $results_per_page . '';
```

The query is:

```
SELECT
  homepost.homeID, homepost.homeTitle, homepost.homeIntro,
  homepost.homePost, homeimage.imageName
  FROM homepost
  JOIN homeimage ON homepost.homeID = homeimage.imageID
  WHERE homepost.homeID=homeimage.imageID
  ORDER BY homeID DESC
  LIMIT $this_page_first_result, $results_per_page
```

```html
$results_per_page = 4;

$sql='SELECT * FROM homepost';
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$number_of_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$number_of_pages = ceil($number_of_results/$results_per_page);

if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
  $page = 1;
} else {
  $page = $_GET['page'];

}

$this_page_first_result = ($page-1)*$results_per_page;

then my Query
```

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm using XAMPP PHP MySQL

Comment: It's not the `ORDER BY`, but the `LIMIT` clause. What's the value of `$results_per_page`?

Comment: it would help if you show some rows from the tables. and also what is the value for LIMIT x and y?

Comment: yes, just change the values of the limits and check if it works

Comment: @TheImpaler I'm doing pagination. That's why I have this `$results_per_page` and `$this_page_first_result`. Please see my post again.

Comment: Try the query for the first page -- i.e. with `LIMIT 0, 4`. That should show you both rows.

Comment: Okay. I got it. I'm having miscalculations where I tried computing it. I'm, having a result less than 1. Thats why. Thank you guys!

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes. That's the problem. Miscalculations.